# Invalid Token, State does not match- Auth-0 Error

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am getting an error in Auth-0 authentication. when login clicked then, it throws error "Invalid toekn" state does not match. 
Then it redirect back to login page. 
There is no change made and it is still working fine in staging.

It was working fine few days back. I am running this on local using docker ro run the web (React-JS) and API in PHP. 
Auth-0 credentials are correct and we never made any changes since beginning.

```
  handleAuthentication(success) {
         this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
         if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) 
         {
            this.setSession(authResult);
            success(authResult.idTokenPayload);

          } else if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            this.auth0.authorize();
         }
         });
```

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue myself. I found a few posts and possible solutions about this issue but in my case -- and possibly yours -- it may be something else. On one of my computers, it works fine and on the other computer I'm getting the same error as you even though it's the same exact code on both computers. I'm still investigating to see what could be causing this. In the meantime, here are a few links you may want to look at: https://community.auth0.com/t/invalid-token-state-does-not-match/12212 and another one here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/819

Comment: It could be that `parseHash` is being called more than once. See if this could be the case in your code.

Comment: @Sam, yep. parseHash is called twice.Actually, react rendering the page twice which is causing the issue, in my opinion. i am still struggling to find out the solution. i have googled it a lot but couldn't find any solution. 
Please share with me , if you could resolve this. I will update you if i am able to do so.